# Inserting data into database using AdoDB

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

This is how you insert using AdoDB Databse Abstraction Layer.

```
<?php
include 'adodb5/adodb.inc.php';
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'user2000';
$pass = 'password2000';
$dbname = 'w3cyberlearning';
$conn1 = &ADONewConnection('mysql');
$conn1->PConnect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
// the MySQL insert statement.
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_infor(id,first_name,last_name, email) values(?,?,?,?) ";
     $my_data = array(
     array(1, 'Paul', 'Mark', 'pm@aa.com'),
     array(2, 'Jam', 'Gill', 'jg@aa.com'),
     array(3, 'Mix', 'Alex', 'mlex@aa.com'),
     array(4, 'King', 'Mix', 'km@aa.com')
);

// loop through the array 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($my_data); $i++) {
    $d = $conn1->Execute($sql, $my_data[$i]);
    if (!$d) {
        print 'error' . $conn1->ErrorMsg() . '<br>';
    }
    echo 'Success!';
    echo "<br/>";
    }
```

The data is in array format.

What if I use a form.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
}

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    <input type="number" id="age" name="age" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Now, the data comes from two variables $name and $age.

What I am unable to do is replace the above $my_data with the two variables which collects the data. How do I replace them

Comment: `$d = $conn1->Execute($sql, array($name, $age));`

Comment: @u_mulder, please use answer to answer so that I accept it. Your solution works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see from

```
$d = $conn1->Execute($sql, $my_data[$i]);
```

arguments passed to `Execute` method are query string and array with some values.

So, in your case you can do the same:

```
$d = $conn1->Execute($sql, array($name, $age));
```

where `$name, $age` your variables and `$sql` is your query string.